# When would a finite group be considered as Fp G -Module?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

What conditions are necessary to think of a finite group as $\mathbb F_p$ G-Module? $\mathbb F_p$ is a finite field with $p$ elements.

Comment: By $Fp$ do you mean the finite field of $p$ elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If (and only if) the finite group $G$ is a group of automorphisms of an elementary Abelian $p$-group $V,$ then $V$ is an $FG$ module, where $F$ is the field with $p$ elements ($p$ 
being prime).

Comment: An elementary Abelian $p$-group is an Abelian group generated by elements of order $p$.

Comment: please could you mention a reference containing this fact

Comment: One of the first papers where this idea was exploited was a paper by P. Hall and G Higman in Proc London Math Soc 1956. You an probably read about it in almost any contemporary reasonably advanced text on finite group theory ( eg Aschbacher)

Comment: thanks I hope you recommend more references about representation theory

Comment: @user135186 This shouldn't require a reference, only thinking. In order for $\Bbb F_p[G]$ to act on $H$, we need both $\Bbb F_p$ and $G$ to act on $H$. In the first case we need $H$ to be a $\Bbb F_p$-module, which is equivalent to an abelian group of exponent $p$, and in the second we need $G$ to act as automorphisms on $H$.